# What to do about downvotes not based on the merits of an answer?

Tags: discussion

A sensitive user has inferred some off-topic political subtext, to what I am confident is a helpful, straightforward answer for English learners. This particular question is currently being promoted on other sites. It's the first thing a lot of new users will see, meaning that it currently represents the first impression of quality that people will expect from this site.

[you're out a dollar -- what does that actually mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/youre-out-a-dollar-what-does-that-actually-mean/55722#55722)

It's fine if someone doesn't understand or care for the word play, but it is hardly the appropriate place to inject political rhetoric. It is a disservice to English learners to downvote a helpful answer based on something like that.

Do users have any recourse in a situation like this? My motivation for asking is not based on my reputation, but based on how downvotes affect the way answers are perceived. As far as I know, it's up to the community to weigh in on stuff like this so that one user isn't tipping the balance. But is there any recourse when a downvote is pretty blatantly unrelated to English?

As helpful as this site could be for English learners, the community has a responsibility to objectively encourage the use of proper English and make it clear when this is not the case. If that is not the general consensus for an English Q&A then what is the point of this Q&A?

That was my best answer, but I went ahead and made the answer a community wiki for anyone who thinks they can to better to correct what is, in my opinion, a failure to help English learners. I know you're still in beta, but step your game up if this is supposed to be a serious resource for English learners.

Comment: Could you bring evidence of why the answer is helpful? To the people in chat at least, it doesn't seem so, and that's in the first reading.

Comment: I don't see any evidence from the comments that the downvote was in bad faith.

Comment: I was referring to the claim it "ends with an extremely judgemental conclusion based on obnoxious socioeconomic stereotypes." It doesn't. Nor does that have anything to do with the English in question. Bad faith, in my opinion.

Comment: I think the reason folks are down voting is because the writing is difficult for someone who is learning English. Frankly, I had trouble figuring out your point as a native speaker.

Comment: I mean, if that one comment is removed, would pointing out that "You're out a dollar" is improper English have been downvoted? It doesn't seem that way based on his comment.

Comment: @ColleenV It was only one downvote, which is why I brought it up after reading the comment.

Comment: You are a native English speakers and you are having trouble figuring out the point of my answer? Would any of you actually say "You're out a dollar?" Seriously people, can't we set a decent example for people looking to learn English?

Comment: Reasons it is helpful: "You're out a dollar" is improper English. I answer the question as to what it means based on proper English. I also suggested a better alternative for the *intended* meaning, "You've lost a dollar." It is the only answer to cover both the intended meaning and the failure to convey that meaning due to improper use of English.

Comment: I did the best I could, but it's a wiki now so if you feel you can convey that message better than I did, feel free to edit it. My main concern was the reason for the downvote with all of the political rhetoric.

Comment: You can flag comments as not constructive.  Down votes are anonymous and trying to match them to comments that don't explicitly say that they DVed is not a good idea. I comment on concerns about answers that I didn't DV often. Instead of getting defensive,  maybe it would be better to try to understand why the commenter took away the wrong impression from what you wrote.

Comment: Well that's a good point

Comment: @iyrin - Downvotes indicated disagreement, not bullying. RE: _would pointing out that "You're out a dollar" is improper English have been downvoted?_ I would downvote that sentiment without reservation. Hopefully others would as well. The examples listed in snailboat's answer here do a good job of refuting that erroneous assertion.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer received downvotes both because it's incorrect and because of certain statements with non-factual implications.  I don't believe the downvotes were made in bad faith.

I've gathered a few examples from [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English* (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) to illustrate the construction in question, which I'll call the ***be out* NP** construction:

> "When does your option expire?" "Actually, it expired the end of July, but we renewed it for another six months till her estate could be settled and I could tender my offer to you through Mr. Howe here." "So if I said no, you'd **be out a lot of money**?"
>
> I'm this far away from the abyss. I'm going to start screaming soon, and then you're going to have to kill me, and then you'll have nothing. Nothing. You'll **be out a year of room and board and the cost of cremation**, and nobody's going to trade you anything for me.
>
> "But what if they send me back?" "Send you back? From Mars? After getting you here? Who can afford to send anyone back? Don't talk crazy at me!" He laughed, saying that. Even so I detected a grain of truth in what he said. If I messed this up, I might **be out a job—but not a planet**.
>
> If you're caught drinking and driving in New York, you**'re out a set of wheels**.
>
> Even if you think Bill Gates has enough money and doesn't need more of yours, heed a warning from Detective Bembry about buying pirated software: "You aren't just hurting Microsoft. I know people don't worry if Microsoft **is out a few dollars**. But I hope you don't want to support organized crime."
>
> As it was a Sunday, I never bothered to take a look at the meter, let alone fish for a quarter. When I returned, much to my chagrin, my windshield sported a $30 ticket for a meter violation. Sure enough, on the meter was a warning that meters must be paid every day, so I guess I**'m out $30**.
>
> I convinced myself that Dave was a con man planning an elaborate sting to separate me from my down payment. The year we had spent together was the setup for the graft. Now I was going to **be out $25,000 and a boyfriend**. It was a hop, skip and a jump from there to standing at the side of the road, homeless and utterly alone, the victim of aiming too high.
>
> There are a lot of divorce lawyers that have watched this very closely, and they say, "Jack Welch, when all is said and done, he's going to **be out $300 million or $400 million, at a minimum**."
>
> The program keeps track of the bikes via tiny RFID chips, the same tamper-proof radio-frequency devices used to monitor everything from clothing inventories to office ID badges. Riders use a swipe card to unlock the bikes, and if they fail to return them – or if the bikes are stolen on their watch – they'll **be out $200**.

As you can see, there was no shortage of examples, many of which were from published, edited writing.  In fact, there were many more examples in the corpus, not only in fiction and transcribed speech, but from non-fiction sources like Time Magazine.  It seems that you're unfamiliar with this particular construction, but I think the corpus evidence shows that it's an established part of the language with relatively consistent semantics and grammar.

Could this be a dialect difference?  It could be, but I can't find any evidence that it's a regionalism, and as it happens, we're both American English speakers who live in the same state.  Despite that, I'm familiar with it and you're not.  It's probably an idiolectal difference—each of us has our own version of English, never quite the same as anyone else's.

You wrote your answer based on your personal feelings and intuition, not research.  That's okay, but this time around it didn't work out, so people downvoted.  If you stick around here on ELL, it's likely you'll run into more bits of English you're unfamiliar with or have never really thought about before.  When that happens, I hope you'll take the opportunity to learn.  After all, that's why we're here on ELL!

**Remember, we're all learning English, even if it's our native language!**

Hopefully we'll never stop learning :-)

Comment: I did research it. I even went so far as to look into the definition of the word "out".

Comment: People should be given the choice to whether they wish to use slang or a grammatically correct phrase. That others choose to use slang does not qualify it as grammatically correct. I really don't see how pointing out that it is grammatically correct warrants a downvote. All that is left is the political motivation which is rather annoying and inappropriate.

Comment: @iyrin Ot is grammatical. This is proven by the fact that native speakers say it. "Grammatical" means *what people who speak a language say" :)

Comment: Incorrect. A native speaker saying something does not automatically make it grammatically correct. If I use. for example.   periods instead of commas. it does not become grammatically correct simply because I am a native speaker.

Comment: @iyrin Maybe not if you alone say it, but if a lot of other folks do, it becomes part of the language. There are many many examples of idioms that can't be parsed with a dictionary.

Comment: Yet dictionaries have the decency to disclaim when a word is informal/slang. Why is everybody here so opposed to giving the reader this information so they can decide if they wish to use informal English? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ginormous

Comment: I can't believe people are downvoting a community wiki that explains that a phrase is informal. The funniest thing is that this all started with that "socioeconomic stereotype" rhetoric by someone who probably has much more socioeconomic privilege. "Hey don't talk bad about the poor, you ignorant poor person!" The downvote had nothing to do with the answer. It is informal English. Even snailboat agrees with that. Why downvote for telling people this? This is cyber bullying and you clearly don't like poor people or care about English.

Comment: @iyrin I think that characterizing people disagreeing with you as cyber bullying isn't constructive. Also, attacking someone's character when they point out something that rubbed them the wrong way in your answer is not a good way to argue your point. You're convinced you're correct. Some other people are convinced you're wrong. You're not going to persuade them to change their minds if you insist that they are just disagreeing with you to be mean.

Comment: I totally get what you're trying to say, but it sounds like victim blaming. Anyway, I don't expect to get anywhere with this so I'm just going to drop it. Just really thought bring up socioeconomic stuff was highly inappropriate.

Comment: @iyrin Lol, victim blaming? You're pulling out all the stops. OK, I see that my attempts to help were quixotic. I'm out.

Comment: Well I mean, just calling it was it is. First the guy attacks my character saying I hate poor people, not realized I am limited in how much I can work and then people rally behind that and ignore the actual topic which is English. Nobody has shown the phrase to be formal English, yet they all downvote me for pointing out that it's not based on a character attack. It's not very mature, but I'm not here to be insulting or for reputation (It's a community wiki. Doesn't even affect reputation). It's like people here hate English.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being unfair or unreasonable in thinking you guys would stoop to personal attacks. If I'm mistaken then I apologize. I've posted what I believe to be a much better answer with resources to support it. I would be surprised to see it downvoted, as I don't believe there is any fodder for political motivation in this one. I fully expect anyone who disagrees to refute it with well supported facts. Please refrain from voting for personal reasons. I wouldn't do that and expect the same courtesy. It's a community wiki anyway so feel free to improve upon it. Thanks!

Comment: @iyrin - RE: _I did research it. I even went so far as to look into the definition of "out"._ Sometimes the simplest words are the hardest to define – at least, the hardest to define _fully_. I don't know where you did your "research", but [this page](https://www.wordnik.com/words/out) lists 50 adverbial definitions, with 25 more as an adjective, 21 as a noun, 11 as a verb, and a handful more as well, along with 40 synonyms & equivalents, including _out on, out in_, and _out of_. You're completely mischaracterizing the people here: we **love** English, most especially its complexities.

Comment: It's true. I find myself reexamining words I take for granted all of the time.